React native web app not changing background color even after app.json web change
I'm building my app with react native. I want the same code and UI for all three platforms. Web, Android, and, IOS. This is my app.json file
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "game-app",
    "slug": "game-app",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "backgroundColor": "#14206b",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#14206b"
    },
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#14206b"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png",
      "backgroundColor": "#14206b"
    }
  }
}

What I'm trying to do is change the background color in my web app for the whole application setting. I have changed the app.json like the above code. But it's still not working. It works on my android well.
Here's the JS codes:
App.js
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import StartGameScreen from './screens/StartGameScreen';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <StartGameScreen/>

  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

StartGameScreen.js
import {View, TextInput} from 'react-native'
import PrimaryButton from '../components/PrimaryButton';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';


function StartGameScreen() {

    return (
        <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
            <TextInput/>
            <PrimaryButton>Reset</PrimaryButton>
            <PrimaryButton>Confirm</PrimaryButton>
        </View>
    )

}

export default StartGameScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    inputContainer: {
        padding: 16,
        height: Platform.OS === 'web' ? 100 : 100,
        marginTop: 100,
        margin: 50,
        backgroundColor: '#72063c',
        alignItems: 'center',
        width: Platform.OS === 'web' ? '95vw' : '95vw', // Adjust width for web
    }}
)


As it is being changed in the app.json, reloading might work. It works for me as well. Also make sure the inputContainer cover up the entire screen, as it is having a different color. As you are using 95vw, I think you can see the different background color.

After spending a lot of time reading react-native documentation, I realized that when you apply a background color in the app.json, it doesn't apply in IOS  as intended.
You can achieve this by using expo-system-ui as recommended by the expo team

The background color for your app, behind any of your React views. This is also known as the root view background color. Requires expo-system-ui be installed in your project to work on iOS.

What documentation says on backgroundColor property
